# php image upload 500 internal server error

Tags: php

There is an error when uploading an image on server.It shows 500 internal server error.If i upload small image than everything is ok but when upload large size image there is above error.
This is working on local but error on live server.

Comment: Look into your `error.log` for the actual error message. Otherwise it's guessing. (Question: Too localized.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check you upload_max_filesize in php.ini

```
Echo ini_get ("upload_max_filesize");
```

Also, read this:
http://www.radinks.com/upload/config.php

Comment: I check this it is 80M but problem is yet please help me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Please hardcode the path of the large image in you upload script, and then see what errors it gives you

Answer (score 1):

it was:

mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 131308 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)

so I've changed the limit by adding this to global httpd.conf (from cPanel):

MaxRequestLen 15728640

and everything is running fine....

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your `php.ini` file
2. Change `memory_limit=128M` to `memory_limit=256M`
3. Press `ctrl+s` to save the changes
4. Restart your `Apache` or `Nginx` Server
5. Now upload any image file of `any size`
6. If the error still persists then `Repeat from Step-1 above`
7. Keep increasing the `memory_limit` till the server accepts big files. but dont forget to save the changes and restarting of server or else it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

check this allowed time to execute your script using below,

```
echo $maxExeTime = ini_get('max_execution_time');
```

and check how much time your script takes and increase the time execution before execution of your file upload script to increase it you can use below code

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

check your php.ini file

```
upload_max_filesize
```

Comment: I check it is 80M. I don't understand why this problem is occur when uploading large size image.