# Laravel 4 image upload

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

Hi, I'm trying to make an image upload via laravel, everything is working but now I want to change the upload to an jquery upload instead but then I get an `500 internal server error`

so when I handle things with Jquery it fails. Anyone knows what the problem might be?
html:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => '../public/posts/add', 'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'id' => 'addPin', 'files' => true)) }}

            <div id="validation-errors" class="alert alert-danger" hidden>
                <p>Some errors occured</p>
                <ul></ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Image Type -->
                <span id="type-image" class="type-media">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            {{ Form::text('Image-title', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '')) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Choose file</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            {{ Form::file('Image-file') }}
                            <p class="help-block">Only .jpg, .png, .gif, .bmp allowed.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            {{ Form::textarea('Image-description', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '3')) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </span>


            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{ Form::submit('Close', array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'data-dismiss' => 'modal')) }}
                {{ Form::submit('Pin it, babe!', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Jquery

```
addPin.on('submit', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var errorForm = addPin.find('div#validation-errors');
    $.ajax({
        url: '../public/posts/add',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        data: addPin.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            errorForm.hide();
            errorForm.find("ul").empty();
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.success == false) {
                var arr = data.errors;
                console.log(arr);
                $.each(arr, function(index, value){
                    if (value.length != 0){
                        errorForm.find("ul").append('<li>'+ value +'</li>');
                    }
                });
                errorForm.show();
                } else {
                location.reload();
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Something went to wrong.Please Try again later...');
        }
    });
    return false;
} );
```

PHP

```
public function postAdd(){
        if (Auth::check()){
                    $rules = array(
                        'Image-title' => 'Required|Min:3|Max:255|alpha_spaces',
                        'Image-description' => 'Required|Min:3',
                        'Image-file' => 'image',
                    );

            $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return \Response::json(['success' => false, 'errors' =>  $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()]);
            } else {
                        $post = Post::create(array(
                            'user_id'   => Auth::user()->id,
                            'title'     => Input::get('Image-title'),
                            'description' => Input::get('Image-description'),
                            'type'      => 'Image',
                        ));

                        $file = Input::file('Image-file');

                        $destinationPath    = 'img/';
                        $extension          = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $filename           = 'usr_'.  Auth::user()->id . '_post'.$post->id .'.'. $extension;

                        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                        $post->imgLocation = $filename;
                        $post->save();

                DB::table('board_post')->insert(['board_id'  => 2, 'post_id'   => $post->id]);

                return  \Response::json(['success' => true]);//*/

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use the CSRF filter? Is so, you need to pass the token to your ajax post data.

Answer (score 3):

You should have an error in your `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` file stating the exact error. Setting PHP to show all errors is preferable in a development environment tho, so you might want to consider turning those on, so you'll get a more descriptive message than just "500 Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 0):

> Check you upload_max_filesize in php.ini
>
> ```
> Echo ini_get ("upload_max_filesize");
> ```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600407/php-image-upload-500-internal-server-error)

Comment: this isn't the problem, I both changed the value to 2G, and used smaller images then 2M.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due the fact that Jquery/JS don't really support Image upload

I fixed the problem by when you click on the button, the form get's validated (via ajax) and show the errors when there are, otherwise it does the normal form sending (the one if I wouldn't do the `event.prefentdefault()`)

this works for now, prehaps I'll have a second look at it to make it completly AJax, but probably not :)